# Securing access to files outside of war

Tags: tomcat, spring-security

I have a web app built with Spring 3.1, using Spring Security 3.0, deployed under Tomcat 6. Certain pages within the site are only available to users with the ROLE_MEMBER role. One of the pages presents a dynamic list of files available for download. Users are able to upload new files using a secured form within the app. My question is: Where can I store the files so that access to them is secured by Spring Security? I currently haven them within the web application folder, but that makes deploying new versions of the app painful since I have to back up the files and restore them after Tomcat re-deploys the new version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security can secure some URL or method invocation. It can't secure your files. So it is not important where your file is. It is important using which URL user can download some file.

Example:

```
http://domain.com/files.html - list of files
```

Corresponding files:

```
http://domain.com/files/file1.pdf
http://domain.com/files/file2.doc
http://domain.com/files/file3.png
```

Security conf:

```
<intercept-url pattern="/files.html" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
<intercept-url pattern="/files/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_MEMBER')" />
```

Actual file paths (they are not important from security point of view):

```
/home/user/uploads/file1.pdf
/home/user/uploads/file2.doc
/home/user/uploads/file3.png
```

Of course you need some servlet/controller that will be responsible for sending a file content by given URL.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the perspective. I'll code a servlet to stream the files from outside the web app.